How to slant the edges in the given graph?
I am unable to draw the following graph in tikz.
I tried the following code in tikz but it is not producing the desired output. Can someone please help me out.
 \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (1) at (0,6) {$1$};  
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (2) at (-2,3)  {$2$};   
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (3) at  (-6,0) {$3$};  
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (4) at  (-4,-3) {$4$};  
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (5) at (6,-4) {$5$}; 
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (6) at (4,0) {$6$}; 
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (7) at (3,1) {$7$}; 
        \draw(1) to (2);
        \draw    (1) to[out=135,in=225] (3);
        \draw    (1) to[out=180,in=230] (4);
        \draw    (1) to[in=45,out=38] (5);
        \draw    (1) to[in=35,out=25] (6);
        \draw    (1) to[in=40,out=35] (7);
        
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

I am unable to produce the edges in the exact form as shown in the given diagram. Can someone please guide me?

Among the many ways of creating this graph, here's one that uses only Tikz's native commands, without using a single specialized library.
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \p [evaluate =\p as \angle using 360*\p/7+50] in {1,...,7}
        \node[shape=circle,draw=black] (\p) at (\angle:3) {$\p$};  
 \foreach \x [remember= \x as \lastx (initially 7)]in{1,...,7} \draw (\lastx)--(\x);  
      
\draw(4)--(7)--(2)--(5)--(7)--(3)--(5);

        \draw    (1) to[out=170,in=140,looseness=1.2] (3);
        \draw    (1) to[out=160,in=180,looseness=2] (4);
        \draw    (1) to[in=30,out=30,looseness=1.7] (5);
        \draw    (1) to[in=80,out=20,looseness=1.3] (6);       
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you so much, it was really helpful.

+1 for you , thanks dear
